# Automatic abbreviation in bacterial taxonomy - multiple species of one genus

Tags: acronyms

In microbiology, the first time a species name is used, it should be written the genus and species in full (Escherichia coli). For all other occurences, the genus should be abbreviated (E. coli).

I managed to do this by using the glossaries package.

Nevertheless, when another species is cited, for example Escherichia fergusonii, it should be directly abbreviated E. fergusonii if E. coli has already been cited to avoid repetitions.

What I used so far to automatically abbreviate the genus names:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{coli}{%
    name = {\emph{Escherichia coli}},
    description = {},
    text = {\emph{E.~coli}},
    first = {\glsname{coli}}
}

\newglossaryentry{fergusonni}{%
    name = {\emph{Escherichia fergusonii}},
    description = {},
    text = {\emph{E.~fergusonii}},
    first = {\glsname{fergusonni}}
}


\begin{document}

A list of bacteria: \gls{coli}, \gls{fergusonni} 

\end{document}
```

- Current output: A list of bacteria: Escherichia coli, Escherichia fergusonii
- Desired output: A list of bacteria: Escherichia coli, E. fergusonii

I would like Latex to detect automatically if the genus was already cited, and not forcing the abbreviated form manually in the glossary command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to print a glossary, you can do without that big package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newspecies}{mmm}
 {
  \sabine_new_species:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\species}{sm}
 {
  \textit
   {
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
     {
      \sabine_print_species_full:n { #2 }
     }
     {
      \sabine_print_species:n { #2 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_head:n { e }

\prop_new:N \g_sabine_genus_prop
\prop_new:N \g_sabine_species_prop
\seq_new:N \g_sabine_genus_used_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sabine_new_species:nnn
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_sabine_genus_prop { #1 } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_sabine_species_prop { #1 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sabine_print_species:n
 {
  \seq_if_in:NxTF \g_sabine_genus_used_seq { \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_genus_prop { #1 } }
   {% the genus has already been used
    \tl_head:e { \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_genus_prop { #1 } } . \nobreakspace
   }
   {% print the full genus
    \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_genus_prop { #1 }
    % mark it as used
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_sabine_genus_used_seq { \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_genus_prop { #1 } }
    \space
   }
  % print the species name
  \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_species_prop { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \sabine_print_species_full:n
 {% bypass the check
  \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_genus_prop { #1 }
  % mark it as used
  \seq_if_in:NxF \g_sabine_genus_used_seq { \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_genus_prop { #1 } }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_sabine_genus_used_seq { \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_genus_prop { #1 } }
   }
  \space
  % print the species name
  \prop_item:Nn \g_sabine_species_prop { #1 }
 }
  
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newspecies{coli}{Escherichia}{Coli}
\newspecies{fergus}{Escherichia}{Fergusonii}
   
\begin{document}

A list of bacteria: \species{coli}, \species{fergus}.

Here a full name: \species*{fergus}.

\end{document}
```

I set up property lists for genera and species. When `\species` is found, the short name (`coli` and `fergus` in the example) is examined. If the genus has already been used, just the first letter is used (followed by a period and `\nobreakspace`), otherwise the full genus name is used. Then the species name, everything in italics.

I also provide `\species*` that prints the full genus name (and marks it as used anyway).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to move `Escherichia` into its own glossary entry like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{esch}{%
    name = {Escherichia},
    description = {},
    first = {\emph{Escherichia }},  
    text = {\emph{E.~}}, %define spaces here to use non breaking space only in abbreviated form
}

\newglossaryentry{coli}{%
    name = {\emph{Escherichia coli}},
    description = {},
    text = {\gls{esch}\emph{coli}},
}

\newglossaryentry{fergusonni}{%
    name = {\emph{Escherichia fergusonii}},
    description = {},
    text = {\gls{esch}\emph{fergusonii}},
}

\begin{document}
A list of bacteria: \gls{coli}, \gls{fergusonni} 
\end{document}
```

A possible issue will be if you are planning to use `\printglossary` as the entry for `Escherichia` will print too - if this is the case please let us know so this can be modified out. If you are not planning on printing your glossaries then hopefully this helps.

Comment: I do not need to use \printglossary so this solution solves my problem ! One detail to improve this : I defined the spaces in \newglossaryentry{esch} to use a normal space when using the full form, but a non breaking space when using the abbreviated form.

Comment: @Sabine feel free to edit my answer to include your modifications with the space and `~`, I'm assuming you put the `~` after `text={\emph{E.}~}` in the `esch`? entry